# How to resolve models in CUD operations not on PK but on UUID?

Tags: python, django, strawberry-graphql

The default CUD operation in `srawberry_django` identifies the model to be mutated by the model's id (the database's id column, which is the Primary Key). How can I change this behavior to point to a column's/model's UUID without overriding `strawberry_django.mutations.update` method?

In simple terms, how to do a search on a field that is not id/PK in [strawberry-graphql-djang](https://github.com/strawberry-graphql/strawberry-graphql-django) without mending `update` method?

Comment: Can you share your graphql type declaration? I think you can set the field class like     ```id: auto = strawberry.django.field(field_name='model_uuid')```

Comment: Thanks @OluwafemiSule I have tried it, and it doesn't work. I share the way with my answer  :)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment of [strawberry-graphql-django](https://github.com/strawberry-graphql/strawberry-graphql-django/tree/7508300d6cf6f3488ea652b6ff784e46ec98fb7b) `v0.16.0` it's not possible to do so! The reason is the implementation of [get_pk](https://github.com/strawberry-graphql/strawberry-graphql-django/blob/7508300d6cf6f3488ea652b6ff784e46ec98fb7b/strawberry_django/mutations/fields.py#L251) method.

```py
def get_pk(data: dict[str, Any],) -> strawberry.ID | relay.GlobalID | Literal[UNSET] | None:
    pk = data.pop("id", UNSET)
    if pk is UNSET:
        pk = data.pop("pk", UNSET)
    return pk
```

As you can see, this method assumes that the model identifier is `id` or `pk` ONLY!

Answer (score 0):

I have added a [feature](https://github.com/strawberry-graphql/strawberry-graphql-django/issues/348) to resolve by custom key in update and delete mutations of `strawberry graphql django`, whis is available from verion starting from `0.21.0`:

```
@strawberry_django.partial(SomeModel)
class SomeModelInputPartial:
    unique_field: strawberry.auto

@strawberry.type
class Mutation:
    update_model: SomeModelType = mutations.update(
        SomeModelInputPartial, key_attr="unique_field")
    delete_model: SomeModelType = mutations.delete(
        SomeModelInputPartial, key_attr="unique_field")
```